# Returning an assoc array from function is Undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a function that gets information from JSON then inserts it into an array.
I then make the function return the array.

I want the code to work like so:

```
user = getUserInfo();
console.log(user["fname"]);

function getUserInfo(){
    userArray = new Array();
    var url =  "./php/getUserInfo.php";

    $.getJSON(url, function( data ) {
        userArray["fname"] = data[0].first_name;
        userArray["lname"] = data[0].last_name;
        userArray["username"] = data[0].username;

        console.log(userArray["fname"]);
    });

    return userArray;
}
```

When I log the value of the userArray["fname"] in the function, it works perfectly.

When I log the value of userArray["fname"] after the function has been called, I get
"undefined"

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the array outside of the `getJSON` callback. Because the call is asynchronous, you won't be able to "return" the data in a traditional sense, but you can call another method and pass the array to it after it has been created.

```
var user; // initialize global
getUserInfo();

function getUserInfo(){
    userArray = new Array();
    var url =  "./php/getUserInfo.php";

    $.getJSON(url, function( data ) {
        // set fields
        setUserInfo(userArray);
    });
}

function setUserInfo(userArray){
    user = userArray;
}
```

After the series of calls, `user` will bet set to the `userArray` array.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning the Array before its values are set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that AJAX calls like `getJSON()` occur asynchronously (the first A in AJAX).

So the `return userArray` will happen while you are still waiting for a server response to your AJAX call.

You will need to handle whatever you want to do with the user info (i.e update some element on the page, update a variable in javascript's global scope, etc.) within teh callback function of `getJSON`.